# Force the user to select only one specific cell

Tags: vba, excel

I cannot lock my sheet because I need to access some cells to run macros.

I want a macro that selects cell (F1) whenever the user try to select any other cell.

I need a macro like this one, I guess:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


    End Sub
```

Comment: Do you know you can Unprotect and protect a sheet within VBA? It might be easier to lock your sheet for all, and unlock while executing your macro! ;)

Comment: Well, I know that, but there's a lot of times in my code where I access this sheet, I would have to lock and unlock it several times.

Comment: You can protect ranges and just leave open the ones you need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763205/lock-certain-cells-in-a-range

Comment: It sounds like you are at a point where you might want to start looking into using a form..

Comment: @EzequiasLopes : Just unprotect at the start of your code execution and reprotect at the end, so just 2 times per procedure/runtime, not bad...

Comment: How about lock everything, except that single cell and apply `UserInterFaceOnly:=True`.  You'll need to add code to the workbook open event to reset it each time, but will mean only your code can make changes to cells.  http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-macro-protected-sheet.htm

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook suggestion should keep the structure intact and allow you to execute any code (without the unprotect-protect-again cycle)

Comment: Well, both suggestions are good. Although my macros should be able to select cells. @DarrenBartrup-Cook, I did not know about this possibility. I will try it.

Comment: Would any of you take a look at this bug (http://bit.ly/1KXjeuf) that I found? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Put this code in the worksheet module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Call Cells(1, 6).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: He wants "a macro that select this cell (F1) whenever the user try to select any other cell". Anyway, I think it is impossible to change any cell without selecting it before (unless you use VBA but I suppose users will not use VBA).

Comment: This should do it +1, but the user will be able to paste 100 values (all over the place)

Comment: Would any of you take a look at this bug (http://bit.ly/1KXjeuf) that I found? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Like other guys wrote, is better to unprotect the sheet, play your macro and protect the sheet but, if you think that disable all cells, minus the cell that you identify, is the best way, you can use this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F10")) Is Nothing Then 'use your free cell
        do
    Else
        Application.Undo
        MsgBox "you can modify only the cell(F10)" 'Just to inform what is the cell editable
        Range("F10").Select
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Would any of you take a look at this bug (http://bit.ly/1KXjeuf) that I found? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 options:

.

**1. Without protecting the sheet** - in each sheet module to customize "unlocked" cell (Ex. "C3")

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With Target
        If .Column <> 3 Or .Row <> 3 Or .CountLarge > 1 Then Application.Undo
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With Target
        If .Column <> 3 Or .Row <> 3 Or .CountLarge > 1 Then Cells(3, 3).Select
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

---

.

**2. Protecting the sheet** - in ThisWorkbook module

---

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        protectWS ws
    Next
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    protectWS Sh
End Sub

Public Function protectWS(Optional ByRef ws As Worksheet = Nothing) As Boolean
    If ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet
    If Not isWSProtected(ws) Then
        ws.Protect Password:=vbNullString, _
                   DrawingObjects:=True, _
                   Contents:=True, _
                   Scenarios:=True, _
                   UserInterfaceOnly:=True, _
                   AllowFormattingCells:=False, _
                   AllowFormattingColumns:=False, _
                   AllowFormattingRows:=False, _
                   AllowInsertingColumns:=False, _
                   AllowInsertingRows:=False, _
                   AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=False, _
                   AllowDeletingColumns:=False, _
                   AllowDeletingRows:=False, _
                   AllowSorting:=False, _
                   AllowFiltering:=False, _
                   AllowUsingPivotTables:=False
    End If
End Function

Private Function isWSProtected(Optional ByRef ws As Worksheet = Nothing) As Boolean
    isWSProtected = ws.ProtectContents Or _
                    ws.ProtectDrawingObjects Or _
                    ws.ProtectScenarios
End Function
```

---

- Option 1 forces users to cell C3

  - can be moved to ThisWorkbook module, with parameters for row and column
- Option 2 is using an empty password, and allows VBA execution (`UserInterfaceOnly`)